# cutting glass tiles with a miter saw

Tags: glass, cutting, saw, miter, wet

Lowes sells 10" square mirror tiles that I need to cut down to a smaller size (about 6" across).  I am struggling with a handheld glass cutting tool (about the size of a pen) getting straight consistent edges.  I was thinking maybe my sliding compound miter saw might do the trick.  Just as a test I made a very shallow cut into one of my tiles, but it just shattered.  I even created a jig to keep things tight and square during the scoring process.  That worked better, but still not great.

If I buy a diamond blade meant for wet saws, would that work in my miter saw?  I was thinking at a minimum I could score the tile very evenly and then it would break off cleanly.

Any suggestions on how to get these tiles cut evenly?

Comment: I doubt you can successfully cut glass with abrasives. The glass cutting tool (really just for scoring) is the best way to go. Use a straightedge, and practice practice practice (those tiles are pretty cheap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont try to cut glass on a mitre saw.  the blade goes too fast and other than the glass particles destroying every moving part of your saw (including the teeth), you are essentially trying to detonate a hand grenade this way

the key to cutting glass is the following:

1)  make sure you are using a sharp scoring wheel.  if you cant remember the last time you rotated or replaced the wheel, its time to do so.

2)  use light oil on your cut.  just dribble a little line of it down where your cut is going to go.

3)  use a straight edge.  just clamp (gently) or double sided tape a straight edge to the glass plate.  remember when positioning it to take into account offset for the thickness of the tool

4)  score once and once only.  slow, with even pressure is the key, from one edge all the way to the other

5)  put a thin wood or metal bar under the glass and push down on both sides to break the piece off.  dont try to hold one side over a table edge or something and snap down.  this technique is only for professional glaziers

6)  debur the edge with a diamond cloth, rock cloth or a diamond flat file.  dont try to use sandpaper or a sanding block.

7)  above all else, wear good quality work gloves or cut proof gloves and a faceshield or good safety glasses

Comment: Why not sanding paper or sanding block?

Comment: in fairness, you can use a sanding block or sandpaper, but you have a much higher chance of a bad cut and the paper will dull quickly.  even silicon carbide or zirconium carbide will dull much faster than diamond.   it also doesnt cut as nicely as diamond (leaves little pits in the edge) its really a personal preference as even alox sandpaper will do the job.